# OfType extension method is missing after the recent Xamarin Studio update

Tags: linq, xamarin, extension-methods, xamarin-studio, oftype

After recent Xamarin Studio (Mac OS) update I'm no longer able to build my PCL with `OfType` extension method usage. For some reason it starts to complain that method is not there:

> Error CS1929: Type `object[]` does not contain a member `OfType` and
>   the best extension method overload
>   `System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.OfType<namespace.TetsClass>(this
>   System.Linq.ParallelQuery)` requires an instance of type
>   `System.Linq.ParallelQuery` (CS1929)

If I create a new test project - it works fine with exactly the same code so the issue in my existing project and/or some referenced projects.

Xamarin Studio information:

```
Xamarin Studio Enterprise
Version 6.1 (build 5441)
Installation UUID: e6dcef46-0a84-444e-bcfd-8be8b1a3b2b1
Runtime:
    Mono 4.6.0 (mono-4.6.0-branch/746756c) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 406000245

NuGet
Version: 3.4.3.0

Xamarin.Profiler
Not Installed

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 8.0 (11246)
Build 8A218a

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 10.0.0.6 (Xamarin Enterprise)
Hash: 6c3fee4
Branch: xcode8
Build date: 2016-09-09 13:01:32-0400

Xamarin.Android
Version: 7.0.0.18 (Xamarin Enterprise)
Android SDK: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        4.0.3  (API level 15)
        4.1    (API level 16)
        4.2    (API level 17)
        4.3    (API level 18)
        4.4    (API level 19)
        4.4.87 (API level 20)
        5.0    (API level 21)
        5.1    (API level 22)
        6.0    (API level 23)
        7.0    (API level 24)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.2
SDK Platform Tools Version: 24.0.3
SDK Build Tools Version: 24.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Xamarin Android Player
Not Installed

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 2.10.0.99 (Xamarin Enterprise)

Build Information
Release ID: 601005441
Git revision: 68292d1ab289911c815ddc715dd7cc29a9752f9f
Build date: 2016-09-09 04:43:23-04
Xamarin addins: ed25d008672663eeb9db55f1ccecb3c24d2fd3b2
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle8
```

Comment: This is described in the release notes as a known issue. Also bug reports should be filed on bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: An no workaround as I understand so the only way to fix it is to manually downgrade to the previous version. I tried Aug version but it gave me same errors so I rolled back to the June version of Mono (4.4.1) and June version of Xamarin Studio + Xamarin.iOS + Xamarin.Android. Now it works again

Comment: @Cheesebaron, are you referring to this issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44402